# Session state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm working on facebook android sdk. I'm getting the hash key using following code .Now I'm getting error **Session state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED** after login to Facebook.

Ref : [if(session.isOpen()), facebook login on android always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176832/ifsession-isopen-facebook-login-on-android-always-returning-false)

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "your.root.package", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: The only way the Key Hash will change is when the signing key changes. And this never happens on it's own. If you are still developing and deploying via USB using the default `debug.keystore` and you delete it and re-create a new one is the only scenario I can think of. And, unfortunately, in the eventuality that the Key Hash has changed, the new Key Hash has to be **manually updated** in your Facebook Developer console. There is no such feature (_and for a good reason too_) that allows your app (regardless of the platform) to edit / modify details in your FB Dev console.

Comment: My actual problem is getting session state equals to false every time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176832/ifsession-isopen-facebook-login-on-android-always-returning-false

Comment: If you are facing the same problem as the one in that question, the code you have used will fix it. Having said that, my earlier comment still remains valid. _but my app is not work when hash key on facebook is automatically changed_: As mentioned earlier, it **does not** change on it's own. _hash key is change on Facebook or any other way to set hash key programmatically from android app_: It **cannot** be done. You will have to update the new Hash Key manually in your Facebook Developer console.

Comment: Ok.I will try suggestion of deleting debug.keystore

Comment: NO NO! I am **not suggesting / asking** you to delete anything!! I was listing a possibility of when the Key Hash will change!! Again, **do not delete anything**.

Comment: dont worry it will recreated when I run my app again. I try this step but still same result

Comment: No I am not worried. It's just that doing so is not a solution and neither was I suggesting it was. In fact, I am not even sure what the real issue is. Perhaps a little details added to the OP would help.

Comment: I can not find the exact problem.can you suggest me what can I do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34529/discussion-between-kirit-and-siddharth-lele)

Comment: getting error after login `Session state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED`

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I am having same problem, and i have already checked my hashkey...

Answer (score -1):

OK MY SONS! LISTEN TO THIS SOLUTION AND BE SAVED

go to this solution and folow carefully:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1

now pay close attention:
you must do it with java 1.6!!

in my case i did it twice like he suggested on my original keystore file  as well-not sure if this
is essential.

last but not least:
go to the android developer site and press Status and Reviews
make your app public and open champein!

(i really hate face)